# Lexical category of "that"

Tags: lexical-semantics, determiners

I am having a bit of trouble with my linguistics homework.

I know "that" is a determiner. However, I am less sure of its lexical category in this sentence: "Ginny likes that." I know that a sentence is composed of a subject and predicate. In this sentence, would "that" be a noun?

Comment: That _that_ is part of a paradigm, which is true of most pronouns. Some of the paradigmatic categories overlap the ones that appear in [this paradigm](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Paradigm.html).

Answer (score 3):

As Jlawler stated in his comment, the *that* in the sentence in the question is a singular distal demonstrative pronoun.

```
a. Ginny likes that.
```

It is a pronoun because it appears where a noun would often appear, e.g. *Ginny likes cake*, and because its content, i.e. what it refers to, is available in context.

One can note in addition that the word *that* functions in a number of other ways, in addition to being a demonstrative determiner or demonstrative pronoun. It can also be a demonstrative adverb, e.g. *It was that controversial*. Perhaps its most common use in English is as a subordinator (i.e. a subordinate conjunction), e.g. *They said that it was finished*. And yet another use of that is as a relative pronoun, e.g. *The people that were present were hungry*, although its status in such cases (i.e. whether it is indeed a relative pronoun or not) is a matter of debate. Here is a list of its uses:

1. demonstrative determiner: *Ginny likes that cake*.
2. demonstrative pronoun: *Ginny likes that*.
3. demonstrative adverb: *Ginny is that hungry*.
4. subordinator (i.e. subordinate conjunction): *Ginny said that she likes the cake*.
5. relative pronoun (controversial): *The cake that Ginny likes is chocolate*.

Answer (score 2):

In the case you've provided, `that' is a (demonstrative) *pronoun*, which only works if you already know what it references (or can ostensively define it)

Comment: Specifically, it's the English singular distal demonstrative pronoun; _this_ is the English singular proximal demonstrative pronoun. _Those_ and _these_ are the respective plurals. There are several other _that_'s, however, and not all of them are demonstrative pronouns, or even pronouns at all.

Comment: @jlawler And there used to be even more: in EME *that* could head a free relative clause as either subject or object, and in OE *that* acted as the n.sg. definite article - in fact, *that* and *the* have switched roles, for *the* was then the subordinating particle.

Answer (score 0):

I would formulate it a bit simpler. "that"  is a demonstrative adjective that you can use with or without a noun. When you use it without noun grammars call it a pronoun.
Actually when you say "That is a book" you mean "That thing is a book" and you simply drop "thing".  So the pronoun "that" is a bit different from a pronoun like "he" . When you use "he" 
you haven't dropped a noun.
In my private terminology I say "absolute use" when "that" is used without a noun.

Answer (score 0):

A determiner does not stand alone.  It is a place in a sentence.  Just as there are subjects and predicates in every sentence (or it is not a sentence) they are made up of nouns, pronouns (of all kinds) and verbs.  In this way a determiner can be the demonstrative pronoun "that".

Comment: Determiners can't be pronouns.   However, a word can have more than one grammatical role across sentences.   "That" is a determiner in some contexts, a pronoun in others, and a complementizer in others.